# Better way to manage MVC razor (or any .net) Layout pages between local , staging and production

Tags: asp.net-mvc, production, asp.net-mvc-layout

There must be a better way to update links inside the layout/master page when publishing, I need to do this since I host my static contents in CDN and it should be linked differently since I have a shared CDN folder between many applications for some static contents and another part is only used by the app.  that are used than  on local machines. I don't want a to put server code to test anything as its useless to add code that test that on production, I was thinking is there a way to make layout pages like web.config where you create one file with debug added to layout name which will be picked locally while the release one is the one that get published.

performance is very important to me and i do no want any extra call that can be eliminated. 
I don't want to be running a code that never be needed when you move the app to production.

Basically i hope there is a way to publish a different version of the layout page that point to the correct static contents since this will be the best way performance wise, MSBUILD should have that but i can not find the info.

Comment: Generate them dynamically. That's the best answer you're gonna get without more details.

Comment: thank you @AntP I edited the question with more info

Comment: What does "linked differently" mean? Provide examples. Your question is way too vague.

Comment: apologize for that , I updated that again with this "Basically i hope there is a way to publish a different version of the layout page that point to the correct static contents since this will be the best way performance wise, MSBUILD should have that but i can not find the info."

Answer (score 0):

Do you means static file like Javascript,Css & Images.

In your MVC app just make a global variable called CDN_Path. Define the appsetting in web.config so you can define the CDN path through web.config.

use this variable like this

```
@(Globals.Root_Path)Images/Test.png
```

Now anytime you move your CDN from Amazon S3 to somewhere else you can use it without any headache. Just change the value in web.config (when you change CDN) make it work everywhere in your site.

Comment: I have used that technique before, but that mean you are running a code that never be needed when you move the app to production, performance is very important to me and i do no want any extra call that can be eliminated

Comment: @Laith The overhead of doing something like this is absolutely negligible - I'm not sure I would go with globals rather than some web.config setting and configuration adapter - but doing some hacky "publish a different view" approach rather than just using dynamic values (which is the canonical way of making things environment-independent and the whole point of a web application) is a bad idea.

Comment: @AntP I didn't get "publish a different view" approach rather than just using dynamic values". What it means ?

Comment: @Laith For me I didn't use CDN but our Codebase use Globals Variable in c# code that make it easy to call images. Even we publish our app in Directory it will work. You can use same thing by make custom Html helper and pass them value of CDN_Path. Use those helper in html page certainly make your code worked.